# How can I center this with foundation front-end frame work?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

```
.row.navigation
  .small-12.columns
  %ul.inline-list
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} HOME
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} RESUMÉ
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} CONTACT
```

I want to center the above navigation bar directly on the page. I've tried everything and it's killing me. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center a column using the `*-centered` class. For example:

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="small-3 small-centered columns">3 centered</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

```css
/*** Foundation CSS ***/
.inline-list {
    margin: 0px 0px 0.94444rem -1.22222rem;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inline-list > li {
    list-style: outside none none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.22222rem;
    display: block;
}
/**********************/

.nav-container {
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-container ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="inline-list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    <li><a href="#">Resume</a>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to center the ul element in the middle of the row class. The above isn't working.

Comment: @mendoncakr updated to show you how to center the actual unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

When using HAML, it's important that your indentations are correct. The answer posted by luke2012 should work; however your inline list should be nested within the columns div. Currently it is only nested within the row.

The code below should work:

```
.row.navigation
  .small-12.columns.small-centered
    %ul.inline-list
      %li
        %a{:href => "#"} HOME
      %li
        %a{:href => "#"} RESUMÉ
      %li
        %a{:href => "#"} CONTACT
```